# Report individual changes to data

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, c#

I need to produce a daily extract on the individual changes to a dataset. So, there are 14 tables containing product and customer information and the extract must only show records from each table that are newly entered or records that have had any column updated.

What would be the best way to do this please?

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2, and develop in C#.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to know what column has changed in the changed records? If not, you can probably just have a `created_date` and `last_updated` against each record in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've used [Change Tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx) to handle this.  We've found it lightweight and easy to set up and administer.  The largest system's moving tens of thousands of rows (from a table containing millions) per day without signs of stress. Of course your configuration will dictate your throughput.

It's big cousin - Change Data Capture (CDC) - will handle the case where you need to know the "before" and "after" values for each and every change that happens.

Answer (score 1):

The "best way" is a matter of opinion, but I've previously created separate logging tables on which I've built custom reports.

The logging tables can be populated by the application or using triggers.

- If your application (app or stored procedures) does the logging you will have to identify and modify each and every bit of code that performs those updates to the 14 tables, and you should also restrict ad-hoc write permissions to users other than the application (perhaps using application roles). I personally like the `OUTPUT` clause for logging modifications and inserts.
- If you choose to go with a trigger solution, keep them short and efficient in order to minimize deadlocks and lock contention.

As a rule of thumb, you should identify the purpose and use of your logs already at design-time. For instance, should logs be human-readable or machine-readable? Are there any metrics that you will need to aggregate? Do you need an audit trail or just versioning?